# How to Send a image from a Fragment to an Activity (AndroidStudio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment{
private FeatureCoverFlow coverFlow;
private FoodAdapter foodAdapter;
private List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
private TextSwitcher mTitle;
private Context mContext;
private Dialog myDialog;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    initData();
    mTitle = (TextSwitcher)view.findViewById(R.id.mtitle);

    myDialog = new Dialog(getContext());

    mTitle.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            TextView txt = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_title,null);
            return txt;
        }
    });

    final Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_top);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_bottom);

    mTitle.setInAnimation(in);
    mTitle.setOutAnimation(out);

    foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(foodList,getContext());


    coverFlow = (FeatureCoverFlow)view.findViewById(R.id.coverFlow);
    coverFlow.setAdapter(foodAdapter);

    coverFlow.setOnScrollPositionListener(new FeatureCoverFlow.OnScrollPositionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolledToPosition(int position) {
            mTitle.setText(foodList.get(position).getCaption());
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolling() {

        }
    });


    /**
    coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(getContext(), FoodDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Food INdex",i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });**/
    coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected Food:" + foodList.get(position).toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),FoodDetailActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return view;

}





public void initData(){



    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("photos");
    DB.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Food item = new Food(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("image_path").getValue().toString(),dataSnapshot.child("caption").getValue().toString());
                foodList.add(item);
                foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I want to Click on a Image in a Fragment (Firebase Database) 
and than i want to see exactly the same image in a new Activity......

```
public class FoodDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

KenBurnsView food_image;
TextView food_title, food_caption;


private List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
private FoodAdapter foodAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

    food_image =(KenBurnsView)findViewById(R.id.food_image);
    food_title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_title);
    food_caption =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_summary);




    if (getIntent() != null){

        int food_index = getIntent().getIntExtra("Food_Index", -1);
        if (food_index != -1)
            loadFoodDetail(food_index);
        }
    }





public void loadFoodDetail(int index) {


    Food food = Common.foodList.get(index);


    Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage_path()).into(food_image);
    food_caption.setText(food.getCaption());
    food_title.setText(food.getCaption());
}
```

...... I read a lot of tutorials but i don't know why but i didn't understand it. 
So if someone have a idea , please share it 
I tried to do it with intent but it didn't work 
Maybe i need a new AdapterClass for my Activity but than there is another problem , how can i get the same imageURL ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass Value through Intent through fragment to activity and set that in to the Imageview of Activity.

Comment: thanks i tried a lot of different stuff , but it didn't work .